# How to access device style in Android?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

On my mobile device I can see that I have a certain palette set in the style settings:

[image]

and these colours are used to colour the notifications bar and also some of the elements in my application

[image]

How can I obtain this colour to use as the background for my compose `TopAppBar`, and is this available across all version of Android or only some?

Comment: Is that Dynamic Colors? https://codelabs.developers.google.com/jetpack-compose-theming#4

Comment: @Abhimanyu that seems to be what I'm looking for, thank you